# Easiest way to insert a JS array into MySQL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, insert

**UPDATE!! My code is actually valid to run. The original question is below. If you are still curious please read the question and then back to read my update.**

My bad, the db actually can get updated successfully after the code runs. I accidentally set the datatype in the table as INT but my initial intention, varchar.

But from HenryDev's answer I managed to find the acquired array by post method in php becomes STRING type but array type. I used

```
$cameArray = $_POST['cameArray'];
echo gettype($cameArray);
```

to output "string" on my screen, so implode would not work oh that(see the discussions on HenryDev's answer).

However his answer will work as a charm if you set up an array in PHP and implode it, it will give you back a "string type" of your array!

**UPDATE!! My code is actually valid to run. The original question is below. If you are still curious please read the question and then back to read my update.**

**Here is my original question**

So I have a very basic question but the tutorials and answers I found online are kinda complicated for my situation.

I have a JS array like

```
var sentArray = ['1','2','3'];
```

I want to insert this array into the database as one field of a table. I use ajax to send this array to PHP and then execute the query in PHP. For instance,

```
$cameArray = $_POST['cameArray']; //then $cameArray is sentArray

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO thisTable (arrayField) VALUES ($cameArray)");
```

And then I want the value in the database shown as "1, 2, 3", but the problem is the value in the database is simply shown as a single "2". The type in table is varchar.

No any JSON object involved just pure text. How could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: And the problem is what? seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. The problem is the value in the database is simply shown as a single "2". The type in table is varchar.

Comment: A mandatory: you must not concatenate queries with parameters yourself, and instead use the prepared statements.

Comment: @Hang is your JS array only numbers?

Comment: Thanks @zerkms you are right! In my script I used pdo and bind parameters but here just wanna keep it simple haha

Comment: Thanks @HenryDev, no they are string type. I just wanna keep it simple here. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Hang by keeping it "simple" you're making it "complicated" just use JSON and be done with it.

Comment: @HenryDev Yes I see it! I was actually running your solution and verify the result. However, in my PHP when I echo $cameArray, I got a '10'! I don't know what's going on so I keep debugging and that's why it takes kinda long. Maybe there's somewhere in my code that causes the problem. I will take a another look and see

Comment: @Augwa my bad... I haven't learned JSON yet. I started it too quick with knowing only basic JS and some jQuery. Will definitely learn JSON soon!

Comment: @Augwa my bad, the db actually can get updated successfully after these code runs. I accidentally set the datatype in the table as INT but my initial intention, varchar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. If you want to store the array as an string simply do this in your PHP code.

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3'); // Your array  
$cameArray = implode(",", $array);

echo $cameArray; // "1,2,3"
```

Now you can store the variable `$cameArray` in your Data Base. Hope it helps!

Comment: What if any of the values contained a comma?

Comment: @zerkms he said he's expecting numbers as the array elements, Any thoughts on how to deal with the commas mate?

Comment: I'm not sure I can find where they mentioned it's only numbers there. But in any case I would not invent a serialisation algorithm and use JSON.

Comment: @zerkms good point, but what's your best approach to this question then? post your answer and will vote it up myself.

Comment: It's too vague. Ideally one described the real problem: there is a chance the proper solution would be to normalise schema.

Comment: @zerkms fair enough mate!

Comment: HenryDev, @zerkms Thanks for both of you guys' help you guys are awesome! I'm still debugging my code by the method provided above. Will get back soon

Comment: @HenryDev I put your code in a PhpFiddle and it works like a charm! But in my php the implode method returns nothing... I guess when php got the array from ajax the array changes some format itself in php? So implode wouldn't work on that array?

Comment: I tried to echo the array got from the ajax and alert the original array and compare, the alert box show exactly same thing as 1, 2, 3... What could be the reason the implode(",", $cameArray) could return nothing...?

Comment: @HenryDev OMG I know what my problem is! I accidentally set the datatype as INT! Ughh! Then after my initial code executes the db is updated succesfully. I used gettype on $cameArray and php gives me "string", so if I just insert it into the db it could show correctly. But thanks anyway, and your implode method does work on php array. 

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the db actually can get updated successfully after the code runs. I accidentally set the datatype in the table as INT but my initial intention, varchar.

But from HenryDev's answer I managed to find the acquired array by post method in php becomes STRING type but array type. I used

```
$cameArray = $_POST['cameArray'];
echo gettype($cameArray);
```

to output "string" on my screen, so implode would not work oh that(see the discussions on HenryDev's answer).

However his answer will work as a charm if you set up an array in PHP and implode it, it will give you back a "string type" of your array!